# Rails number_field with delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This tag won't show my number (because commas aren't numbers):

```
<%= number_field_tag 'name', number_with_delimiter(number, delimiter: ','), min: 0 %>
```

This will:

```
<%= number_field_tag 'name', number, min: 0 %>
```

I know I can use a text_field:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', number_with_delimiter(number, delimiter: ','), min: 0 %>
```

But I like using number_field to constrain input to only numbers and keep the actual value as a number.

Any way to get everything I want?

- number_field_tag displayed with delimiter, actual value without delimiter
- text_field_tag that constrains input to numbers, displays with delimiter, actual value without delimiter

I could use some JS to do this, but, is there a rails way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so about Rails built-in method but I have an idea and I have worked with this when not finding an appropriate solution for many searching.

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, class: "form-control", maxlength: "11", placeholder: "2,00000" %>
```

You keep the text_field to your input field then add below js code

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $( "#form_id" ); // Your form id
    var $input = $form.find( "#input_field_id" ); // Input field ID which you need number with delimiter

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {
        // When user select text in the document, also abort.
        var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
        if ( selection !== '' ) {
            return;
        }
        var $this = $( this );
        // Get the value.
        var input = $this.val();

        var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
            input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;

            $this.val( function() {
                return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "en-US" );
            } );
    } );
});
```

Now input field not supported any text or zero or special character only number.

You can modify based on your requirements like how much number get input and not supporting minus or zero.

Now it can send number with delimiter, you can modify this using befor_save method like

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
   before_save {self.name = self.name.gsub(/[\s,]/ ,"")}
end
```

See the console

```
cd = Model.new(name: "1,3,4,3,2")
=> #<Model id: nil, name: "1,3,4,3,2", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
cd.save
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tables" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "13432"], ["created_at", "2018-02-06 04:00:00.851630"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-06 04:00:00.851630"]]
(13.2ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

That's it

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for this, why the arrow key abort?

Comment: Sorry! @Chiperific, I have used it different purpose, this not need for your requirements, I have updated the answer removing this condition

Comment: Thanks, I'll borrow some of this, but I was really hoping for a rails way. After more thought, expecting the static page to impose this constraint is a bit out of scope for rails and more within the purview of JS or JQuery on the client-side.